# Проблема с скриптов входа на сайт

Tags: mysqli

Скрипт входа на сайт отлично работал на Mysql, как только я его перевел на Mysqli он тут же перестал работать корректно.
Скрипт выбивает "Wrong username or password".

Вот собственно сам скрипт:

```html
        if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['captcha']))
        {
            if ($_POST['captcha'] === $_SESSION["captcha"])
            {
                $username = clean($_POST['username']);
                $password = md5(clean($_POST['password']));
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $config['table_users'] . " WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
                $result = mysqli_query($data_sql, $sql);
                if (!$result)
                {
                    echo sql_error();
                } else
                {
                    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    if ($count == 1)
                    {
                        session_start();
                        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                        $userId = $user["userId"];
                        $regDate = $user["regDate"];
                        $userType = $user["typeId"];
                        $_SESSION["userId"] = $userId;
                        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                        $_SESSION["regDate"] = $regDate;
                        $_SESSION["userType"] = $userType;
                        header("location: index.php");
                    } else
                    {
                        $respond[type] = "danger";
                        $respond[text] = "Wrong username or password";
                    }
                }
                @mysqli_free_result($result);
            } else
            {
                $respond[type] = "danger";
                $respond[text] = 'Wrong captcha';
            }
        }
```

Comment: `session_start` нужно запускать в самом начале скрипта, а вы запускаете его внутри блоков, причем сверху у вас есть условие `$_POST['captcha'] === $_SESSION["captcha"]` не кажется ли вам это странным? А вообще, проще `recaptcha 2.0` поставить и да - `isset` поддерживает оператор `and so on` - и так далее, это значит, что можно писать так: `isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['captcha'])` и у вас `sql-injection` на ровном месте. Плохой код, следует переписать, полностью.

Comment: К сожалению для меня это темный лес" на данный момент.
Скрипт работал на Mysql
А вот на Mysqli нет